# i am trying to make changes to the build.gradle file but every time i run the package

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, build-tools, python-for-android

Please can anyone help me with the commands ran by buildozer after the `gradlew clean assemble debug` i am trying to make changes to the build.gradle file but every time i run the package....... it runs this  `running cp -r /mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/Eagle_2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2 /mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/Eagle_2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/eagleSchools` and recopies the whole thing to overide my editted build.gradle file

In that case, if i can know other commands ran after this, i will be able to do that manually....

....................................................................................................................................c.